# Can't read time data from DB

Tags: vba, datetime, msdasql

I tried to read full date information in the DB file.

When I check the data using DBbrowser, it shows as below

```
Date
4/16/2016 16:39:10
4/19/2016 12:50:48
4/22/2016 16:12:24
4/25/2016 10:28:31
4/27/2016 10:51:30
```

But I can get only date with below code.

```
Date
4/16/2016
4/19/2016
4/22/2016
4/25/2016
4/27/2016
```

Macro:

```
Sub db_query()
'
' db_query Macro
'
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object

Worksheets("results").Range("A2:AI5001").Clear

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' OPEN CONNECTION
conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=D:\backup.db;"

strSQL = "SELECT date from Tb_Result_Summary"

' OPEN RECORDSET
rst.Open strSQL, conn, 1, 1

' OUTPUT TO WORKSHEET
Worksheets("results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close

' FREE RESOURCES
Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try adjusting the Excel cell format to allow for the time portion of the date?

Comment: Yes. I already did it but not worked. When I check the value after rst.open in excel VBA debug, the type is adDBDate and value is #4/16/2016#.